# Are 'reference', 'sense', 'connotation', 'denotation', 'intension', and 'extension' mutually distinct terms?

Tags: terminology

### **Assumptions**

- *Reference*: a unique and real entity that an expression represents.
- *Sense*: a facet of a referent that an expression represents.
- *Connotation*: the settled emotional content of an expression (especially of a word).
- *Denotation*: the meaning of an expression (especially of a word) less its connotation.
- *Intension*: the truth conditions of an expression [1].
- *Extension*: all entities that fulfill the the intension of an expression [1].

### Conflations

My concepts of *extension* and of *denotation* seem the same. For example, it seems to me that the expressions **pro-choice** and **pro-abortion**[2] have the same extension[1], the same denotation, but different connotations. So denotation and extension seem the same to me.

Similarly, my concepts of *extension*, *denotation*, and *reference* seem nearly the same, except that my concept of *reference* includes only expressions that represent unique and real referents.

Also similarly, my concepts of *sense* and of *connotation* seem nearly the same, except that my concept of *sense* includes only expressions that represent unique and real referents.  (E.g. Bruce Wayne and Batman are two senses of the same referent.)

### **Questions**

1. Which, if any, of the aforementioned terms did I incorrectly define?
2. What distinguishes *denotation* from *intension*?

---

Notes

[1] *Some meaningful expressions may not comprise all components necessary to state anything true or false. (I.e. unsaturated predicates or arguments). Logicians and linguists use variables to represent an absent component, such as in **∃x(Px)**, where only **P** has a stated interpretation. In such a case, the intension of the expression **∃x(Px)** is that [[**∃x(Px)**]] is true iff it is true that x exists and that the interpretation of P is true of x.*

[2] *I acknowledge that, strictly speaking, [[**pro-choice**]] ≠ [[**pro-abortion**]]. I disregarded that fact for the sake of the example.*

Comment: You forgot _presupposition, entailment, invited inference, conversational implicature, prototype,_ and _literal meaning._

Comment: @Jlawler Ha. I'm not familiar with invited inference, but I know the other concepts - and they're not part of my conceptual mess - thankfully =)

Comment: So, with those terms but not others, I have no idea at all what you're trying to do. Are you referring to logic or to language? Real (i.e, spoken) language, or technological representation (i.e, writing, smoke signals, talking drums) of real language?

Comment: @jlawler I'm trying to clarify the meaning of the terms I mentioned in the title of the question. (As for the use of logic: Semantics uses logical and lambda notation as a meta-language, logical notation was useful for my question, that's why I used it; the question is not about logic)

Comment: The terms, like all technical terms, have meanings only in the technical context they're defined in. These terms are not defined in the same universes of discourse, so they can't be compared in any simple way. Oh, and only some semantic theories use lambda notation.

Comment: Yeah, absence of a quantifier means some (it means neither 'none' nor 'all')

Comment: Each pair is a binary opposition in a different context. ["Sense and reference"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22sense+and+reference%22) is just a translation of Frege's original _Sinn und Bedeutung_. ["Intension and extension"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22intension+and+extension%22) refer to philosophical systems that distinguish individual internal mental percepts from external perceived referents, if any. It's just an instantiation of the supposed mind/body distinction.

Comment: Finally, ["connotation and denotation"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22connotation+and+denotation%22) are words lexicographers use; _denotations_ means 'things we tell you it means' and _connotations_ means 'things it may also mean'. Covers a multitude of phenomena.