# Composite truth tables for sentence relations (entailment, synonymy,etc.)

Tags: semantics, philosophy-of-language

I'm using John Saeed's 'Semantics'. Now in chap 4 I see he is trying to formalize sentence relations such as entailment, synonymy, contradiction, etc., by some kind of different truth tables he calls composite truth tables(in which he uses arrows to show the direction of inferences for any truth value assigning to propositions.
My question is: Can we reconstruct these tables in usual truth tables as in propositional logic? Why? if yes, is there a general algorithm or rule for it?

PS. An example as a (composite) Truth tabular definition for synonymy he suggests the following:

p        ,      q

T     ->      T

F     ->      F

T     <-      T

F     <-      F

Now my question would be that can we find a composition of formulas containing only p and q and logical propositional connectives?(Or even predicate if necessary) [which is equivalently a usual truth table for it]

For instance defining synonymy as:
(phi  is synonym to  psi) iff [ (phi <-> psi) is a tautology ]

Comment: Though I understand the terms you used, I don't understand your question or its context. Would you like to elaborate on your explanation?

Comment: Not all such relations are truth-functional. Negation, for instance, is not truth-functional in natural language. So truth tables are not usually helpful. See the [Logic guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) for what it possible using formal logic, and [pragmatic concepts](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/predtypes.pdf) like [presuppositions](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/presuptrig.pdf), [invited inferences](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/6718/482), [conversational implicatures](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Grice.pdf), etc. for the rest.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look on the attached papers and ask questions if still unclear...

Comment: @parsh: Well, my question is simply: Is there a way to make a propositional/predicate truth table (i.e., the kind used in propositional/predicate logic) out of a composite truth table(used for some sentence relations)?
And the answer seems to be: not always!... Though I'm still i need of more clarification and have to take a look at the attached papers by jlawer.
Any other help, of course, would be welcomed!